# Docker ENV in CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to do the following:

1. Pass a build arg to my docker build command
2. Store that as an env variable in my container
3. Use it in my CMD to start when my container launches.

Below is my setup:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

ARG EXECUTABLE

ENV EXECUTABLE ${EXECUTABLE}


CMD ["/opt/foo/bin/${EXECUTABLE}", "-bar"]
```

Here is how i'm building container

```
    docker build --build-arg EXECUTABLE=$EXECUTABLE  -t test_image .
```

Here is how i'm running image

```
    docker run -d test_image
```

When I run the container it crashes and tells me

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused 
"exec: \"/opt/foo/bin/${EXECUTABLE}\": stat /opt/foo/bin/${EXECUTABLE}: 
no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To use environment variables, you need to use shell.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

> Note: Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command
>   shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For
>   example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on
>   $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or
>   execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME"
>   ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the
>   case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment
>   variable expansion, not docker.

Based on this, I think you can work fine by the following `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

ARG EXECUTABLE

ENV EXECUTABLE ${EXECUTABLE}

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "/opt/foo/bin/${EXECUTABLE}", "-bar"]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with docker run?

Comment: @soniccool Yes, just pass the env var at runtime like `docker run -e EXECUTABLE=foo <image>`.  Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Comment: It would have to be `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "/opt/foo/bin/${EXECUTABLE} -bar"]`. Otherwise, `"-bar"` will be executed separately or as a parameter of `"sh"` like `"-c"`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write out an executable or shim as `ARG` / `ENV` substitution is not supported for `CMD`.

The list of [supported substitutions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement):

> ```
> ADD
> COPY
> ENV
> EXPOSE
> FROM
> LABEL
> STOPSIGNAL
> USER
> VOLUME
> WORKDIR
> ```
>
> as well as:
>
> ```
> ONBUILD (when combined with one of the supported instructions above)
> ```

A workaround is to write your executable to a file and execute that:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

ARG EXECUTABLE

RUN : \
    && /bin/echo -e "#!/bin/sh\nexec '/bin/$EXECUTABLE' -bar" > /exe \
    && chmod +x /exe

CMD ["/exe"]
```

Build:

```
docker build -t test --build-arg EXECUTABLE=echo .
```

Run:

```
$ docker run -ti test
-bar
```

Comment: This was my understanding from reading the docs too, but the Docker docs are a bit misleading here, since a compatible workaround is to use a shell in CMD to expand the environment variable as shown in @lahsuk 's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789442/149428.

Comment: @TaylorD.Edmiston that's not a substitution, that's the **shell** interpreting an **environment variable**

Comment: I believe we are saying the same thing -- that's why I said the docs are misleading vs incorrect.

Comment: the docs are not misleading -- there is no substitution happening in the accepted answer.  you're just confusing substitution and environment variables (which happen to share some of the same syntax)

Comment: Nothing in my comment or the question mentions substitution

Answer (score 0):

Another way to access the environment variable passed is by running it as:

`docker run -e EXECUTABLE=<some_value> <docker_image>`
Then, in the dockerfile
`CMD exec /opt/foo/bin/${EXECUTABLE} -bar`